# Sequelize is searching table in plural form when calling from ManytoMany relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, many-to-many, sequelize-cli

My 'House' table is in singular form and I want to get the data using ManytoMany Relationship but sequelize is considering 'House' table as 'Houses' and cannot fetch the results(i.e []) calling this like,

```
db.V1_DB.models.Users.findAll(
        include: [
            {
                model: db.V1_DB.models.House,
            }
        ]
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }
    ).catch((ex) => {
        console.log("Error is here: ", ex)
    })
```

But successfully fetches the results of House with Users,

```
db.V1_DB.models.House.findAll(
        include: [
            {
                model: db.V1_DB.models.Users,
            }
        ]
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }
    ).catch((ex) => {
        console.log("Error is here: ", ex)
    })
```

I have already added `freezeTableName: true`

My models are like this.

```
'use strict';

const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class House extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      House.belongsToMany(models.Users, {
          through: "Users_Has_House",
          foreignKey: "Users_fk",
      });
    }
  }
  House.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'House',
    freezeTableName: true,
    
    name: {
      singular: "House",
      plural: "House"
  }
  });
  return House;
};
```

```
'use strict';
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Users extends Model {
        //No Associations

        static associate(models) {
            // define association here

            Users.belongsToMany(models.House, {
                through: "Users_Has_House",
                foreignKey: "House_fk",
            });
        }
    };
    Users.init({
        Bio: DataTypes.TEXT,
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Users',
    });
    return Users;
};
```

Comment: Did you add `freezeTableName: true` to all models?

Comment: Add model definitions to your post

Comment: Yes I have added freezeTableName.

Comment: Added sample details of my model

Comment: Models look ok. Can you add the full error description and stacktrace?

Comment: There is no error. I am just not getting any value in Country(i.e. Empty array)

Comment: I don't see any `Country` in your code? Did you miss to show some other models?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is House. My bad

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct associations because `foreignKey` option should indicate to a model whose `belongToMany` method we are calling and `otherKey` should indicate to a model that is passed as a first argument to `belongToMany`:

```js
House.belongsToMany(models.Users, {
          through: "Users_Has_House",
          foreignKey: "House_fk",
          otherKey: "Users_fk"
      });
Users.belongsToMany(models.House, {
                through: "Users_Has_House",
                foreignKey: "Users_fk",
                otherKey: "House_fk"
            });
```